# Consulta pivot en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql, pivot

Estoy intentando hacer una query en SQL Server que me transforme filas en columnas. 
Cada fila tiene una columna de legajo, otra de fecha y otra de hora.. 
Un legajo puede tener varios registros en un día. 
que seria algo como esto:

[image: TABLA REAL]

Lo que necesito es poder agrupar por legajo, dia y la columna hora que este en columnas una del lado de la otra en forma dinámica. Es decir que diga Hora1, Hora2, Hora3, etc. y que siga en forma dinámica. 
El resultado deberia ser este.

[image: Resultado]

Intente con la función PIVOT pero no he logrado hacerlo. Si alguno puede aportarme algo. Será bienvenido. En principio parece simple pero no logro hacerlo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Cómo lo intentaste? Añade las consultas que probaste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución se puede hacer con Pivot o con funciones agregadas condicionales. En lo personal, prefiero la segunda porque dan más flexibilidad y son más eficientes cuando hay que hacer más de una operación. El único detalle con tu caso, es que le tienes que dar un indicador a tu consulta de como identificar cada fila que se irá a cierta columna. Eso se soluciona usando `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo, al cual solo debes cambiarle el nombre de la tabla.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Legajo, Fecha ORDER BY Hora) AS rn
    FROM MiTabla
)
SELECT Legajo,
    Fecha,
    MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Hora END) AS Hora1,
    MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Hora END) AS Hora2,
    MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Hora END) AS Hora3
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Legajo,
         Fecha;
```

Comment: Excelente Luis. 
Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta, Me sirvió de mucha ayuda.
Solo me restaría poder hacer que las columnas de horas sean dinámicas y no tener que nombrarlas con Hora1, Hora2, Hora3, etc.. Ya que la cantidad de registros de hora pueden ser uno solo o muchos. 

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Justo acabo de responder algo similar en [otro sitio con columnas dinámicas.](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-get-below-query-in-sql-server-2008) Pero recomiendo mantener un total fijo de columnas o hacer la conversión en el front-end.

Comment: Muy bien.. Gracias por todo. Lo voy a hacer desde el Frontend entonces.. 
Saludos